# Multiple Select Options

Tags: jquery, select

I am trying to select items in the following select multiple by there value. The code is below:

```
<select id="genre" name="genre" multiple="multiple" size="9">
    <option value="1">Action</option>
    <option value="2">Adult</option>
    <option value="3">Adventure</option>
    <option value="4">Comedy</option>
    <option value="5">Drama</option>
</select>
```

I can select one or two options but the thing is that the number of selected options comes from user which i'm change it to something like this: `1,2,4` *(by value)*.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're asking - selecting three items isn't anything different than two. `.val([1,2,4])` should work.

Comment: Do you want to automatically select options 1,2,4 based on some input?

Comment: What does your jQuery look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select multiple options by passing an array of values to the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2) function:

```
$("#genre").val([1,2,4]);
```

If instead of an array, you have a comma delimited string, just transform it to an array using `split()`, before passing it to `.val()`:

```
$("#genre").val("1,2,4".split(","));
```

From the docs:

> **[`.val( value )`](http://api.jquery.com/val/#val2)**
>
> **`value`** - A string of text or an **array of strings** corresponding to the
> **value** of each matched element to set as selected/checked.

Answer (score 2):

it is difficult to determine what you are looking for, but since you want to select multiple items and you tagged it as jquery...

```
$('#genre').val([1,2,4]).each(function () {
    $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
```

});​

Comment: No need to set the `selected` attribute. `.val()` already does so.